# Filter elements of a list of lists that contain elements of a list

Tags: haskell

So, to explain the mouthful that is the question...

I'm trying to use filter, and not getting anywhere. So here's the behaviour I want. Given a list of lists (of `Integer`s) ie

```
[[1,2,3],[23456,4,3,2],[1,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[5,6,7],[1,2,5]]
```

I want to take another list ie `[1,2]` and take all the lists that contain **both** those elements. (It doesn't matter if any of the others are preserved at this moment in time, though that might be needed later). So in this example my output would be something like

```
[[1,2],[2,1],[2,1],[1,2]]
```

or preferably

```
[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[1,2,5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to keep a list `candidate` if all elements of the list `criterion` are also elements of `candidate`. Thus your `filter` condition is

```
condition candidate = all (`elem` candidate) criterion
```

which, using `flip` we can write as

```
condition candidate = flip all criterion (flip elem candidate)
```

thus giving

```
filter (flip all criterion . flip elem)
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly does `flip` do?

Comment: `flip` changes the order of arguments, `flip f x y = f y x`. You could also write the filter as ``filter ((`all` criterion) . flip elem)``, but ``condition `all` list`` seems odd to me.

Comment: Ok, and why don't we just change the order?
Basically, I get that we're taking all elements of our criterion and asking if they are elements of what we are filtering. Why does the flip make that work?

Comment: Not sure I understand. `all` and `elem` take their arguments in a defined order, but for the filter condition, we don't receive the arguments in the required order, so we must create functions that do the same but take their arguments in the other order, hence `flip all` and `flip elem`.

Answer (score 5):

First, define what it means for the elements of one list to be a subset of another:

```
> let xs `isSubsetOf` ys = all (`elem` ys) xs
```

Then you can just partially apply this function to get a suitable predicate to filter by:

```
> let xss = [[1,2,3],[23456,4,3,2],[1,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[5,6,7],[1,2,5]]
> filter ([1, 2] `isSubsetOf`) xss
[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[1,2,5]]
```

That'll do for small inputs. For larger inputs, you might want to use `Data.Set` instead of lists.

Comment: I'm likely to want to preserve ordering so I'll have to stick with lists rather than sets :S

Answer (score 3):

```
ghci> import Data.Set hiding (filter)
ghci> let subset xs ys = fromList xs `isSubsetOf` fromList ys
ghci> let xs = [[1,2,3],[23456,4,3,2],[1,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[5,6,7],[1,2,5]]
ghci> filter (subset [1,2]) xs
[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[1,2,5]]
```

Comment: This would be more efficient as `filter (isSubsetOf (fromList [1,2]) . fromList) `, to avoid converting the `[1,2]` list to a set on every `subset` call. (Admittedly a small overhead for such short lists.)

Answer (score 0):

```
similars :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
similars xs  =  filter (\ ys -> all (`elem` ys) xs)
```

meaning

```
similars [1,2] [[1,2,3],[23456,4,3,2],[1,3,4,5,6],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[5,6,7],[1,2,5]]
```

`==`s

```
[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[1,2,5]]
```